# Is it possible to statically link against dynamically linked Qt?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, qt5, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have been wondering wether it is possible to link different libraries dynamically and statically at the same time?
When I have been trying to link Qt5 (dynamically linked) against other libraries that can only be compiled statically and I couldn't get it to work because of this error and a few other errors complaining about multiple definitions of symbols in `msvcrtd.lib`:

```
qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj):-1: Error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for "RuntimeLibrary": value "MDd_DynamicDebug" doesn't match value "MTd_StaticDebug" in main.obj
```

Detailed error messages:
[image: Detailed error messages]

I am absolutely sure that I built all libraries statically and that I added `QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG += /MTd` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MTd` to the .pro file.

Is it not possible to mix dynamic and static linking (in Qt) or am I doing something wrong?

- Qt version: Qt 5.5.1 64Bit
- Compiler: MSVC2013 64Bit

Comment: It's not possible, period. You need to compile Qt in a different way (passing `-static` to `configure`) if you want to static link against it.

Comment: @peppe But if I can't statically link due to licensing issues then building dynamic libraries and linking against them is my only option, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but then it's *dynamic* linking against a *dynamic* build of Qt. Not *static* link against a *dynamic* build.

Comment: @peppe ok, I am going to try that.